# Gain mechanical disadvantage

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I want lift 100 gram with 1kg of force, is this posible, I investigated that with pulleys you can gain mechanical Advantage, but I want to reverse it, is this  posible, what are some ways or examples I can do this?

Comment: kg is a unit of mass, not force. What do you mean by "1 kg of force?"

Answer (score 1):

A mass of 1 kg can certainly lift a load of 100 g if the [mechanical advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_advantage) of the system is at least 0.1.

Note that the 1 kg mass will have to travel at least 0.1 times the distance of the 100 g mass in this process (this is the principle on which [simple machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_machine), like [pulleys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley), work).

To see how mechanical advantage can be less than 1, imagine running a simple machine in reverse.